# Find the area bounded by the parametric curve...

Tags: calculus, parametric

Find the area bounded by the parametric curve $x = \cos(t)$, $y = e^t, 0 < t < \pi/2$, and the lines $y = 1$ and $x = 0$.

I do not even know where to start with this problem. I know that I need to draw a graph, but that's all I know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How would I set up the definite integral?

Comment: when you say and the lines $y=1$ and $x=0$, do you mean "at" the lines $y=1$ and $x=0$

Answer (score 2):

If $x=\cos(t)$, then $t=\arccos(x)$, at least when $0\leq t \leq \pi/2$.  Thus, your curve can be expressed as $y=e^{\arccos(x)}$, which you can integrate over $[0,1]$.

I certainly agree that a picture like the one below is useful.  You could plot both the [parametric plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric%20plot%20%28cos%28t%29,%20exp%28t%29%29,%20t=0..pi/2) and the [function plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20exp%28arccos%28x%29%29,%20x=0..1) using a tool like WolframAlpha.  It then becomes apparent that you should subtract 1 from the integral.  Of course, you can also ask WolframAlpha for help with the integral, which might be a bit tricky.

[image]

Comment: why would you need to draw anything?
evaluate the definite integral

Comment: @boby: What would the be the a and b values for the integral?

Answer (score 0):

To finish the resolution of this problem, we would continue from the graph shown by **Mark McClure** :  the bounding curve is traced out from $ \ ( \ \cos \ 0 \ , \ e^0 \ ) \ = \ ( \ 1 \ , \ 1 \ ) \  $ to $ \ ( \ \cos  \frac{\pi}{2} \ , \ e^{\pi / 2} \ ) \ = \ ( \ 0 \ ,  \ e^{\pi / 2} \ ) \  $  .  The region for which we wish to find the area is thus perched atop a unit square:

[image]

We would set up the area integral as  $ \ \int_0^1 \ y(x) \ - \ 1 \ \ dx \ $ , but to carry this out *parametrically* , we need to account for the curve being traced "backwards" (from right to left):

$$  \int_0^1 \ y(x) \ - \ 1 \ \ dx \ \ \rightarrow \ \ \left[ \ \int^0_{\pi / 2} \ y(t) \ \frac{dx}{dt} \ \ dt \ \right] \ - \ 1 \ \ = \ \ \left[ \ \int^0_{\pi / 2} \ e^t \ ( - \sin \ t   \ \ dt ) \ \right] \ - \ 1 $$

$$ = \ \ \left[ \ \int_0^{\pi / 2}  e^t \ \sin \ t   \ \ dt  \ \right] \ - \ 1 \ = \ \  \frac{1}{2} e^t \ ( \ \sin \ t \ - \ \cos \ t \ ) \vert_0^{\pi / 2}    \ - \ 1 $$

[having integrated by parts twice]

$$ = \ \ \frac{1}{2}  \left[ \   e^{\pi / 2} \ ( \ \sin  \frac{\pi}{2} \ - \ \cos  \frac{\pi}{2} \ ) \ - \  e^0 \ ( \ \sin \ 0 \ - \ \cos \ 0 \ )    \ \right] \ - \ 1  $$

$$ = \  \frac{1}{2}  \left[ \   e^{\pi / 2} \ ( \ 1 \ - \ 0 \ ) \ - \  1 \ ( \ 0 \ - \ 1\ )    \ \right] \ - \ 1 \ = \  \frac{1}{2}  \left( \   e^{\pi / 2} \ + \  1     \ \right) \ - \ 1 $$

$$ = \ \frac{1}{2}  \left( \   e^{\pi / 2} \ - \  1     \ \right) \ \approx \ 1.905  \ \ . $$

Despite the curve not (quite) being a straight line, the area is estimated very well by a triangle of appropriate dimensions: $ \ \frac{1}{2} \ \cdot \ ( \ 1 - 0 \ ) \ \cdot \ ( \ e^{\pi / 2} \ - \ 1 \ ) \ $ .